# CCRepeatForever Error

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I've got a problem in my current game.
I'm trying to move a sprite based on the movement of a other physic body, for a map. This is my code:

```
    ...
    NSMutableArray *mapObjetcs = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
    [mapObjetcs addObject:swordman];
    [mapObjetcs addObject:icon];

    CCCallFuncND* iconMap = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(mapLoc:mapObj:) data:mapObjetcs];
    CCSequence* iconMapSequence = [CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0f/60.0f], iconMap, nil];;
    CCRepeatForever* iconRef = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:iconMapSequence];

    [self runAction:iconRef];
    }

    -(void) mapLoc:(ccTime)delta mapObj:(NSMutableArray*)mapObj
    {
    GB2Sprite *swordmanTemp = (GB2Sprite*)[mapObj objectAtIndex:0];
    CCSprite *iconTemp = (CCSprite*)[mapObj objectAtIndex:1];

    CGPoint swordmanPos = [swordmanTemp ccPosition];
    float pos = (swordmanPos.x/convFactor)+65;
    iconTemp.position = ccp(pos, 290);
}
```

Every time i run the code with the CCRepeatForever the games freezes, if i run the code without the CCRepeatForever the game run grat but dont refresh the icon in map.
Can anybody help me??? Thanks

Comment: whats is exactly the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to describe the error, now i describe the error above, but, every time i run the code with the CCRepeatForever the game freeze, if i run the game without the CCRepeatForever the game run but the icon in map dont refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem with running `CCRepeatForever` on layer itself.. Ofcourse it will freeze the game.. You can try for alternate solution I guess.. Instead of using a separate `CCRepeatForever` loop, use the `update` method of your layer.. As its already doing same thing that you want to do with your own action..

Another solution is make a same `CCRepeatForever` for your icon sprite.. and in its CCCallFuncND take the position of other object....

Hope this helps.. Try yourself.. If it doesn't work.. I'll try 2 give you code... Don't run CCRepeatForever Loop on your layer itself.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, a fix the problem using a global variable to store the position of the enemy. Can you explain me how use the layer update method to do what i want???

Comment: - (void) update:(ccTime)dt
{
         (,,,)
}

This method calls itself.. Just implement it.. Don't forget to add onEnter Method... Read this link http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8663

Comment: I know how use this method but, i dont know how pass one or more paremeters using the schedule, is this possible???

Comment: You can not send data as parameter.. Better solution is keeping an instance variable of your array rather than local variable.. You might need same array else where in the code.. You can't do all stuff by passing variables from one function to another. :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoud such actions you can simply schedule some method with needed interval. smth like

```
[self schedule: @selector(methodToBeCalled) interval: intervalInSeconds];
```

just don't forget to unschedule it later